# Groups rows by all days between two dates

Tags: postgresql

Given two dates `start` and `end`, I would like to group my records on `deviceId` and `days` between this two dates.

If my table looks like and I have `start = 2017-05-24` and `end = 2017-05-27`

```
id   deviceId   data   createdAt
1       1        {}    2017-05-24
2       1        {}    2017-05-25
3       2        {}    2017-05-24
4       3        {}    2017-05-25
5       1        {}    2017-05-01
6       1        {}    2017-05-29
```

I would like to get

```
   days       deviceId    data
2017-05-24        1        {} // id 1
                  2        {} // id 3
2017-05-25        1        {} // id 2
                  3        {} // id 4
```

So far, I my initial plan was:

- to get all the days between the two dates using

  ```
  select (generate_series(start, end, '1 day'::interval))::date as days;
  ```
- to join it with my table
- to group by `days` and `deviceId`

But unfortunately I'm can not manage to write the corresponding query.

Does my query idea seams correct ? Do you know and efficient way to implement it ?

Comment: I would go with `min/max over (partition by deviceId)`

Comment: I do not know partition, I will check the doc

Comment: although - why 2017-05-25 for device 1?..

Comment: Because deviceId = 1 was created at 4 different dates - is my guess. Looks to me like desired result is just sorted table with date removed if next one would be the same, so maybe lead() over() and case would be better?

Comment: device 1 has two rows in the initial table that are between `start` and `end`, one on `2017-05-24` and one on `2017-05-25`. I added more details to my question

Comment: I do not know about `over` and `lead`, but thanks for the idea, I'm checking the docs right now

Comment: lead() gives you value for specified column that is held in next row (null if there is no next row). From your example result this should give it, but it doesn't really group data, so you should maybe give better sample: `SELECT CASE WHEN (lag(createdAt) over ()) = createdAt THEN NULL ELSE createdAt END AS days, deviceId, data
  FROM someTable
 WHERE createdAt BETWEEN date '2017-05-24' AND date '2017-05-27'
 ORDER BY createdAt, deviceId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with my_table(id, deviceId, data, createdAt) as (
values
    (1, 1, '{}', '2017-05-24'::date),
    (2, 1, '{}', '2017-05-25'),
    (3, 2, '{}', '2017-05-24'),
    (4, 3, '{}', '2017-05-25'),
    (5, 1, '{}', '2017-05-01'),
    (6, 1, '{}', '2017-05-29')
)

select 
    case when d = lag(d) over (order by d, deviceid) then null else d::date end as days,
    deviceid, data, id
from generate_series('2017-05-24', '2017-05-27', '1d'::interval) d
join my_table on d = createdat
order by d, deviceid;

    days    | deviceid | data | id 
------------+----------+------+----
 2017-05-24 |        1 | {}   |  1
            |        2 | {}   |  3
 2017-05-25 |        1 | {}   |  2
            |        3 | {}   |  4
(4 rows)
```